# Remove extra generated td values from the table

Tags: php

I'm trying to fill table with values which I'm getting from the database but when I loop though array some values are getting out of the table.

DB values image:
[image]

DB structure with dump:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9gTDRBFnguHtagJC4YNnRg/5

**DB Values Explanation:**

Data column contains JSON format data of users activity.

For example

**January:**

```
{
   "Jan":"1563", // Total users registered in January
   "Feb":"0",
   "Mar":"0",
   "Apr":"0",
   "May":"0",
   "Jun":"0",
   "Jul":"13", // Out of 1563 registered users only 13 users are active in July
   "Aug":"7",  // Out of 1563 registered users only 7 users are active in August
   "Sep":"4",  // Out of 1563 registered users only 4 users are active in September
   "Oct":"0",
   "Nov":"0",
   "Dec":"0"
}
```

**February:**

```
{
   "Feb":"1727",  // Total users registered in February
   "Mar":"0",
   "Apr":"0",
   "May":"0",
   "Jun":"0",
   "Jul":"10", // Out of 1727 registered users only 10 users are active in July
   "Aug":"11", // Out of 1727 registered users only 11 users are active in August
   "Sep":"8",  // Out of 1727 registered users only 8 users are active in September
   "Oct":"0",
   "Nov":"0",
   "Dec":"0"
}
```

Code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM monthly_report";
$result = $this->db->query($query)->result_array();

$data['data'] = $result;
```

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align:center;">Month</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">Total Registered</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">January</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">February</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">March</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">April</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">May</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">June</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">July</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">August</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">September</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">October</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">November</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">December</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <?php
        $num = 0;
        for ($m = 1; $m <= 12; $m++) {
            $month = date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1, date('Y')));
            echo "<tr style='text-align:center;'>";
            echo "<td>" . $month . "</td>";


            $short_month_name = date('M', strtotime("2022-$m-01"));

            if (isset($data[$num]['month']) && $data[$num]['month'] == $short_month_name) {

                $decode_data = json_decode($data[$num]['data'], true);
                $decode_isset = isset($decode_data[$short_month_name]) ? $decode_data[$short_month_name] : '';

                echo "<td>" .  $decode_isset . "</td>";
            }

            $num_1 = 0;
            for ($day = 1; $day <= 12; $day++) {

                $short_month_name_1 = date('M', strtotime("2022-$day-01"));

                if (isset($data[$num]['month']) && $data[$num]['month'] == $short_month_name_1) {

                    $decode_data_1 = json_decode($data[$num]['data'], true);
                    $decode_isset_1 = isset($decode_data_1) ? $decode_data_1 : [];

                    foreach ($decode_isset_1 as $v) {

                        if (!empty($v)) {
                            echo "<td>" .  $v . "</td>";
                        } else {
                            echo "<td>0</td>";
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "<td>0</td>";
                }

                $num_1++;
            }

            echo "</tr>";
            $num++;
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And output is:

[image]

In above output vertical months are registered users count and horizontal rows are their activity.

Example:

In vertical January month 1563 users are registered, in same row horizontal January has 1563 because registration will count as their activity. In same row July month 13 users are active out of 1563 registered users and same goes on for other months of same row.

I'm getting values in expected tds but want to remove extra generated td (Marked in red box).

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you're actually trying to do here. Every row has a specific month, but it also contains columns for all other months. That's confusing. What exactly is it supposed to represent? Either way, the issue is with your "data" value. Each row contains different number of items, so when you iterate through them and create `td`'s for each, it will result in different number of `td`'s on each row.

Comment: M. Eriksson I have edited my question and added "DB Values Explanation" and expected output for your reference.

Comment: Not related to your problem, just a personal critique. If this were my database, because there is a fixed number of months I think I'd prefer to just have twelve additional columns for each month with `null` representing no data. If the JSON data needed to store more I could see using your method, or possibly if someone else needs to consume it in JSON format (although I think I'd still just generate that as needed). But that's just a personal take on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ve got one too many `for` loops, the innermost `foreach` isn’t needed. In fact, because you are working with data that is constrained to known values that must exist in a specific order, you shouldn’t even trust it.

Because you have a database, are dealing with JSON  inside an array, and have a lot of data, it is unfortunately hard to reproduce your code. Instead, I’ve made a simple array that mimics your database with the JSON already decoded, but hopefully it makes sense still.

I usually comment my code more but I think it mostly speaks relative to your code. One major change I added was to use `??` which can make missing array items much easier to read. One known potential bug is if the dates coming out of the database aren’t in the correct order this will render strangely.

```php
$data = [
    ['month' => 'Jan', 'year' => 2022, 'data' => ['Jan' => 1563, 'Mar' => 6]],
    ['month' => 'Feb', 'year' => 2022, 'data' => ['Feb' => 345, 'Mar' => 76, 'May' => 8]],
];

for($row = 1; $row <= 12; $row++){
    $monthNameLong = date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $row, 1, date('Y')));
    $monthNameShort = date('M', strtotime("2022-$row-01"));
    
    echo '<tr>';
    printf('<td>%1$s</td>', $monthNameLong);
    if(($data[$row - 1]['month'] ?? null) === $monthNameShort && isset($data[$row - 1]['data'][$monthNameShort])){
        $total = $data[$row - 1]['data'][$monthNameShort];
    } else {
        $total = '';
    }
    
    printf('<td>%1$s</td>', $total);
    
    for($col = 1; $col <= 12; $col++){
        $colMonthNameShort = date('M', strtotime("2022-$col-01"));
        printf('<td>%1$s</td>', $data[$row - 1]['data'][$colMonthNameShort] ?? 0);
    }
    
    echo '</tr>';
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/JecP1

Comment: Working as expected and thank you for bringing this error to my attention.

Answer (score 2):

Do it all in SQL by using JSON_EXTRACT() so that you don't need any of that PHP monkey-business.

SQL: ([Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9gTDRBFnguHtagJC4YNnRg/8))

```
SELECT CASE `month`
          WHEN 'Jan' THEN 'January'
          WHEN 'Feb' THEN 'February'
          WHEN 'Mar' THEN 'March'
          WHEN 'Apr' THEN 'April'
          WHEN 'May' THEN 'May'
          WHEN 'Jun' THEN 'June'
          WHEN 'Jul' THEN 'July'
          WHEN 'Aug' THEN 'August'
          WHEN 'Sep' THEN 'September'
          WHEN 'Oct' THEN 'October'
          WHEN 'Nov' THEN 'November'
          WHEN 'Dec' THEN 'December'
      END `Month`,
      TRIM('"' FROM COALESCE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, CONCAT('$.', `month`)), 0)) AS `Total Register`,
      TRIM('"' FROM COALESCE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.Jan'), 0)) AS January,
      TRIM('"' FROM COALESCE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.Feb'), 0)) AS February,
      TRIM('"' FROM COALESCE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.Mar'), 0)) AS March,
      TRIM('"' FROM COALESCE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.Apr'), 0)) AS April,
      TRIM('"' FROM COALESCE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.May'), 0)) AS May,
      TRIM('"' FROM COALESCE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.Jun'), 0)) AS June,
      TRIM('"' FROM COALESCE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.Jul'), 0)) AS July,
      TRIM('"' FROM COALESCE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.Aug'), 0)) AS August,
      TRIM('"' FROM COALESCE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.Sep'), 0)) AS September,
      TRIM('"' FROM COALESCE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.Oct'), 0)) AS October,
      TRIM('"' FROM COALESCE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.Nov'), 0)) AS November,
      TRIM('"' FROM COALESCE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.Dec'), 0)) AS December
FROM monthly_report
```

Where I work, we choose to omit 0 values from reports similar to this because it allows users to scan for non-zero values easier.

Comment: Got to learn something new today, thank you!

Comment: This is a great example of the power of SQL. I think as servers have gotten faster and faster over the years, I've seen more `SELECT *` code with PHP (or other server-side language) doing complex loops, temporary array storage, etc., and people aren't using the SQL server itself to the best of the ability.